# Explanation of basic agile principle about individuals and tools

Tags: agile

In agile manifesto and in many answers here, I found this :

> Individuals and interactions over
>   processes and tools.

So, what exactly does it mean?

In my opinion, processes and tools are important part of software development. For example, what is the point of installing continuous integration if people are going to ignore the result for weeks?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it's not within the scope for this site, as defined in [What topics can I ask about here?](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Also see: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](//stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) You may be able to ask on [another Stack Exchange site](//stackexchange.com/sites#name), for example [pm.se] or [softwareengineering.se]. Be sure to read the on-topic page in the help center for any site on which you intend to post a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even the best tools and processes add little value in the hands of inept people.

Focus on building and training a good team vs. buying into the lastest tool/process and hoping it'll solve all your problems.

Comment: +1 for good points. I haven't really thought about those.